# Does the Jetpack Compose API limit to force keyboard to be opened all the time?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**Let's imagine such scenario:**

1. The application requires user to authenticate.
2. The idea is to force keyboard to be opened all the time and block back button to prevent keyboard from hiding.
3. When back button is pressed, user should be able to go back to previous screen only.

I am wondering if Jetpack Compose API allows to force keyboard to be opened even if the back button is pressed.
Or maybe there is a good workaround to achieve such effect?

Comment: That's not a Jetpack Compose issue. That is something related to Android in general. You can always override the back button and prevent it from executing the default action. But what you want to accomplish isn't normal in Android and kind of goes against user interface design. You shouldn't prevent users from closing the keyboard.

Comment: @Johann, thanks for your quick response. I can override the back button and it's simple for `onBackPressed()`, but it's like not being possible to force keyboard to not close on `BackHandler()` using Compose tools. I understand your point of view regarding the UX, but it's a very specific situation and one of the customer's requirements.

Comment: Create your own keyboard using Compose and you won't have this issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.